# Add prefix to ffill, identifying values which were carried forward

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a wayto add a prefix when filling na's with ffill in pandas? I have a dataframe containing, taxonomic information like so:

```
| Kingdom  | Phylum        | Class       | Order           | Family           | Genus         |

| Bacteria | Firmicutes    | Bacilli     | Lactobacillales | Lactobacillaceae | Lactobacillus |

| Bacteria | Bacteroidetes | Bacteroidia | Bacteroidales   |                  |               |

| Bacteria | Bacteroidetes |             |                 |                  |               |
```

Since not all of the taxa in my dataframe can be classified fully, I have some empty cells. Replacing the spaces with NA and using ffill I can fill these with the last valid string in each row but I would like to add a string to these (for example "Unknown_Bacteroidales") so I can identify which ones were carried forward.

So far I tried this  `taxa_formatted = "unknown_" + taxonomy.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)` but this of course adds the "unknown_" prefix to everything in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `mask` and `update`:

```
#make true nan's first.
#df = df.replace('',np.nan)

s = df.isnull()
df = df.ffill(axis=1)

df.update('unknown_' + df.mask(~s) )

print(df)

   Bacteria     Firmicutes                Bacilli        Lactobacillales  \
0  Bacteria  Bacteroidetes            Bacteroidia          Bacteroidales   
1  Bacteria  Bacteroidetes  unknown_Bacteroidetes  unknown_Bacteroidetes   

        Lactobacillaceae          Lactobacillus  
0  unknown_Bacteroidales  unknown_Bacteroidales  
1  unknown_Bacteroidetes  unknown_Bacteroidetes
```

Answer (score 3):

You can this using [`boolean masking`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `df.isna`.

```
df = df.replace("", np.nan)  # if already NaN present skip this step
d = df.ffill()

d[df.isna()]+="(Copy)"
d
    Kingdom         Phylum              Class                Order                  Family                Genus
0  Bacteria     Firmicutes            Bacilli      Lactobacillales        Lactobacillaceae        Lactobacillus
1  Bacteria  Bacteroidetes        Bacteroidia        Bacteroidales  Lactobacillaceae(Copy)  Lactobacillus(Copy)
2  Bacteria  Bacteroidetes  Bacteroidia(Copy)  Bacteroidales(Copy)  Lactobacillaceae(Copy)  Lactobacillus(Copy)
```

You can use [`df.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) here.

```
d = df.ffill(axis=1)
df.add("unkown_" + d[df.isna()],fill_value='')

    Kingdom         Phylum                 Class                 Order                Family                 Genus
0  Bacteria     Firmicutes               Bacilli       Lactobacillales      Lactobacillaceae         Lactobacillus
1  Bacteria  Bacteroidetes           Bacteroidia         Bacteroidales  unkown_Bacteroidales  unkown_Bacteroidales
2  Bacteria  Bacteroidetes  unkown_Bacteroidetes  unkown_Bacteroidetes  unkown_Bacteroidetes  unkown_Bacteroidetes
```